# Limitar o número de casas decimais - JAVA

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Olá!

Comecei há pouco tempo a programar e estou aprendendo java. Estou tentando fazer meu primeiro app, que faz o cálculo da regra de três.
Consegui fazer ele funcionar, porém tive que transformar o resultado do cálculo de double para String, pois estava utilizando o método .setText() para exibir o resultado.
Tenho duas dúvidas:

1. Existe algum método que exibe um double em um TextView? (atualmente estou usando o .setText())
2. Como faço para limitar o número de casas decimais que são exibidas?

Além disso, se eu estiver fazendo algo errado ou existir uma forma melhor de desenvolver o código, aceito sugestões.

Agradeço desde já.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText num1, num2, num3;
    private TextView resultado;
    private Button botaoCalcular;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        num1 = findViewById(R.id.editNum1);
        num2 = findViewById(R.id.editNum2);
        num3 = findViewById(R.id.editNum3);
        resultado = findViewById(R.id.textViewResultado);
        botaoCalcular = findViewById(R.id.buttonCalcular);
        }
    public void calcular(View view){
        String stringNumero1 = num1.getText().toString();
        String stringNumero2 = num2.getText().toString();
        String stringNumero3 = num3.getText().toString();
        double numero1 = Double.parseDouble(stringNumero1);
        double numero2 = Double.parseDouble(stringNumero2);
        double numero3 = Double.parseDouble(stringNumero3);

        //cálculo
        double resultadoCalculo = (numero2 * numero3) / numero1;
        String resultadoCalculoFinal = String.valueOf(resultadoCalculo);
        resultado.setText(resultadoCalculoFinal);


    }
}
```

Screenshot do app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsfn7.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como você está convertendo um double para String, poderia usar o format.

Substitua essa parte:

```
String resultadoCalculoFinal = String.valueOf(resultadoCalculo);
```

Por está:

```
String resultadoCalculoFinal  = String.format("%.2f", resultadoCalculo);
```

Lembrado que o resultado terá virgula, exemplo: 19,58
Você pode fazer um replace caso precise substituindo virgula por ponto ou vice versa.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!